# The completion of a separable inner product space is a separable Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, complete-spaces

Let $X$ be a separable inner product space and $\bar X$ its completion. Then I want to check that $\bar X$ is a separable Hilbert space.

But I am stuck here, because how do you prove that $\bar X$ has a inner product induced by the one of $X$?, and how do you construct a complete orthonormal system for $\bar X$? because the completion is a set of representatives, that we don't even know if they look as the elements of $X$.

But I am a little bit confused and stuck,I think more hypothesis on $X$ to get the result, because well, we know that $\bar X$ by definition, but how do you ensure that it has a inner product? and even more, how do you construct a countable dense set from elements that are abstract?, since we have to recall that all the points that live in the completion are equivalency classes of sequences, so it is hard for me to deal with them.

I know that the completion is the quotient space of the Cauchy sequences of $X$ and the ones that converge to $0$ and $\bar X$ is complete with respect to the metric defined as

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} d(x_n,y_n)$$

but I don't know how to get the result with that.

So Can someone help me to prove this assertion please?

Comment: Can you recall how you construct the completion $\overline X$ and it's metric on it? Everything will be analogous.

Comment: Well the completion is a quotient space of Cauchy sequences right?

Comment: Yes, how about the metric?

Comment: It is $lim_{n \to \infty}d(x_n,y_n)$ of two sequences right?

Comment: Yes, try to do the same thing for the inner product....

Comment: Ok, so I need to use the inner product of a sequence space right?

Comment: Yes. As in the metric case, you have to check that it's well defined. Also the bilinearity, blah blah blah....

Comment: Right, but this is a little bit involve isn't? I was wondering a better way to get that result jajajaja :)

Comment: Is there a better way to do this? :)

Comment: Then, How do you proceed ? Thanks in advance :)