# Proving that the completion is a Hilbert space.

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

I want to prove the following theorem:

Let $X$ be a separable inner product space and $\bar X$ its completeness. Then $\bar X$ is a separable Hilbert space.

But I am a little bit confused and stuck,I think more hypothesis on $X$ to get the result, because well, we know that $\bar X$ by definition, but how do you ensure that it has a inner product? and even more, how do you construct a countable dense set from elements that are abstract?, since we have to recall that all the points that live in the completion are equivalency classes of sequences, so it is hard for me to deal with them.

I know that the completion is the quotient space of the Cauchy sequences of $X$ and the ones that converge to $0$ and $\bar X$ is complete with respect to the metric defined as

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} d(x_n,y_n)$$

but I don't know how to get the result with that.

This is another question because here I am explaining more that the duplicate it, and in fact there I haven't get an answer yet, so that is why I decided to open a new question.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: The inner product gives the norm (and hence the metric) you are completing. The inner product is a continuous function with respect to this norm, so extends uniquely to the completion. This is the universal property of a completion.

Comment: Can you elaborate more in this please?, Is because I am not very familiar with the universal properties and those arguments you used to extend the norm so easily :) Thanks

Comment: Didn't you ask this already? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1524226/the-completion-of-a-separable-inner-product-space-is-a-separable-hilbert-space

Comment: Yes but I thought that no one has interests in that one and I think it has been a long time I have asked that and nobody was viewing it anymore , sorry :) I thought this was a common trick here when your question don't get attention

Comment: Take a continuous function $f:X\to Y$, where $Y$ is a topological space. The property I refer to above is that there exists a unique, continuous function $F:\bar X\to Y$. Take $x\in\bar X$, then there is a sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ converging in to $x$ (as $n\to\infty$). Set $F(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)$. This gives you the unique extension. Apply this to the inner product.

Comment: Ok, but I think it is a little fancy for me, because I haven't seen what a topological space is I think your proof is quite interesting,but Is there a less fancy way to do this?

Comment: Well the codomain is less important. In your case it will be the base field for the inner product space. So either $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, in most cases.

Comment: Right, so then how can you proceed?

Comment: Then how, do you proceed?