# Proving that this is a particular norm

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

Consider the function $||\cdot||_\infty:l^2\to[0,\infty)$ given by

$||(a_n)||_\infty = \sup\{|a_n|:n\ge 1\}.$ So I want to prove that this is indeed a norm.

I did the following, we note that if $(a_n)$ is the constant sequence $0$, then the supremum of all its values is $0$, then $||(a_n)||_\infty=0$. Now, if $||(a_n)||_\infty=0$ this means that $\sup\{|a_n|:n\ge 1\}=0$ but $|a_n|\ge0$ for all $n$ then $(a_n)=0$.

To prove that $||(a_n)||_\infty >0$ we just observe that $|a_n|>0$ (because we have already addressed the $0$ case ) then the least upper bound for all those elements should be positive.
Finally we know that the $\sup$ is linear, so we consider $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and the set $C=\{|\lambda a_n|:n \ge 1\}$ of a given sequence $(a_n) \in l^2$, but $|\lambda a_n|=|\lambda||a_n|$, so if we define $A=\{| a_n|:n \ge 1\}$ then $C=|\lambda|A$ therefore $\sup C=|\lambda|\sup A$.

For the triangle inequality we define $D=\{|a_n+b_n|:n \ge 1\}$,$A=\{| a_n|:n \ge 1\}$,$B=\{| b_n|:n \ge 1\}$, we have then:

$$A+B=\{|a_n|+| b_n|:n \ge 1\}$$

so by the triangle inequality in $\mathbb{R}$ we get

$$|a_n+b_n|<|a_n|+| b_n| \Rightarrow \sup D <\sup A +\sup B$$

So Is my proof right? Or Can someone help me to fix the mistakes please?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: There's a very slight issue with $>0$: You claim that $|a_n|>0$ presumably for all $n$, which is not necessarily true. However, due to part $1$, there is at least one $n$ such that $|a_n| > 0$, and thus, $\sup_{n\ge 1} |a_n| > 0$.

Comment: Can you clarify this part please? is because $|·|$ is a norm in R right?, so it has to be positive unless the number is zero correct?

Comment: Well, it's $0$ iff $a_n = 0$ for every $n$, yes? What if one of those is non-zero, but the rest are? (NB: By part $1$ I mean your proof that $||a_n|| = 0 \iff \forall n ~a_n  = 0 $)

Comment: Right, since I have already talk about the zero case then one of them should be different from zero and your assertion is correct :) right?

Comment: Mm hmm. I know this is pedantic, but it looked like you were going for a 'perfect' proof, so...

Comment: Yes jajaja you are right, so everything else is correct right ?

Comment: Far as I can tell, aye.

Comment: jajajaja ok, I'll trust in you :)

Comment: Can you help me with this one please http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1524226/the-completion-of-a-separable-inner-product-space-is-a-separable-hilbert-space Thanks in advance :)